# Core Data object wrapped with @ObservedObject causes NavigationLink destination to re-render when that object is deleted

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm having an issue where SwiftUI is rendering a View for a Core Data object that was just deleted. I have reproduced this issue using the base SwiftUI+Core Data template Xcode gives you.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var selectedItem: Item?
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var managedObjectContext
  
  @FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
  private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        List {
          ForEach(items) { item in
            NavigationLink(
              destination: DetailView(item: item).environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext),
              tag: item,
              selection: $selectedItem
            ){
              Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
            }
          }
          .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
      }
      .navigationTitle("Items")
      .toolbar {
        Button(action: addItem) {
          Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func addItem() {
    withAnimation {
      let newItem = Item(context: managedObjectContext)
      newItem.timestamp = Date()
      
      do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
      } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
      offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(managedObjectContext.delete)
      
      do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
      } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct DetailView: View {
  @ObservedObject var item: Item
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  @State var show = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Text("Detail item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
      .navigationTitle("Detail")
      .toolbar {
        Button {
          show = true
        } label: {
          Text("Edit")
        }
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: $show) {
        Popup(item: item)
          .environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)
      }
  }
}

struct Popup: View {
  var item: Item
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Popup item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
      Button {
        item.timestamp = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 1, to: item.timestamp!)!
        try! managedObjectContext.save()
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      } label: {
        Text("Add second and close")
      }
    }
  }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateStyle = .short
  formatter.timeStyle = .medium
  return formatter
}()

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NavigationLinkDelete")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                Typical reasons for an error here include:
                * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                * The device is out of space.
                * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
  }
}
```

To summarize, `ContentView` retrieves some items from Core Data and renders them in a list. If the user taps on one, the `NavigationLink` shows `DetailView`. The user can then hit an *Edit* button to open a `Popup` sheet where the user can edit the item (in this case, the user can only add one second to the Core Data `Item` being edited.)

If the user first taps an item in the `List` to see the detail view, navigates backwards to see the `List` again, swipes that list item they had previously tapped, and hits *Delete*, the item will be deleted but the app will crash inside the `DetailView` body when it is trying to retrieve the `timestamp` for an item.

The issue is that `DetailView` observes the `Item` with the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper. I do this because when the user edits the item in the `Popup` and that sheet is dismissed, I want the `DetailView` to update automatically. If I remove that `@ObservedObject` then performing the above steps won't result in a crash, but the `DetailView` doesn't update when the `Popup` is dismissed.

I believe because `DetailView` is observing the `Item`, when the user deletes the `Item` it causes the last `DetailView`'s body to re-render, despite the fact that the `NavigationView` isn't showing an `Item`'s details. The `DetailView` isn't visible at the point the user swipes to delete the `List` row, so it's not clear why this is happening.

I can mitigate this issue by checking `item.isFault` in the `DetailView`'s `body` and only accessing fields if it's false. This seems like a bit of a hack though.

Is this a SwiftUI bug? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I have been running into the crash on delete with SwiftUI
and CoreData as I am learning. I have experienced it on row view implementations and on the detail view on iPad where it is showing.

I see a lot of discussion of the problem, but I think your "hack" might be the best. My solution preference at this time:

1. Use ObservedObject and check for the `item.isFault` to present a placeholder or empty view.
2. If you can, use a `let` of the model object in cases where the view doesn't need to respond to changes and can just go away as the `FetchRequest` change propogates.
3. Do something more complicated where you mark the object for delete at a future time and filter the deleted objects out of the fetch. That way it doesn't go away suddenly and cause a crash. You might want to use the trash and will need to clean it eventually.

It seems like it would be nice for SwiftUI to delay updating views on deleted model objects, but this is all new to me.

This is a FAQ, but I don't see a common answer.